# Convert rows into columns SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have a table that have records collected each Friday, I want my result of last 4 weeks to create a report.

```
|Company  |  User   |  Date      | Login    |
|---------|---------|------------|----------|
|COM1     | USER1   |  7-10-15   | 25       |
|COM1     | USER1   |  7-03-15   | 26       |
|COM1     | USER1   |  6-26-15   | 37       |
|COM1     | USER1   |  6-19-15   | 30       |
|---------|---------|------------|----------|
|COM2     | USER2   |  7-10-15   | 21       |
|COM2     | USER2   |  7-03-15   | 35       |
|COM2     | USER2   |  6-26-15   | 49       |
|COM2     | USER2   |  6-19-15   | 25       |
|---------|---------|------------|----------|
|COM3     | USER3   |  7-10-15   | 50       |
|COM3     | USER3   |  7-03-15   | 20       |
|COM3     | USER3   |  6-26-15   | 22       |
|COM3     | USER3   |  6-19-15   | 33       |
|---------|---------|------------|----------|
```

How I can use pivot or other logic to make it like below ?

```
|Company  |  User   | 7-10-15 | 7-03-15 | 6-26-15 | 6-19-15 |
|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|
|COM1     | USER1   |  25     |  26     |  37     |  30     |
|COM2     | USER2   |  21     |  35     |  49     |  25     |
|COM3     | USER3   |  50     |  20     |  22     |  33     |
```

Comment: And what's expected to happen when the date 7-11-15 suddenly shows up in your table?

Comment: The suggested example have columns name fixed in rows, but i have variable ( date ) in rows to show in columns

Comment: bluefeet can you pls check mu comments and reopen the question